# Making a flutter app that gives push-notification whenever new notice is posted on university homepage

Tags: flutter, authentication, push-notification

I am creating a Flutter app that gives push-notification whenever a new notice is posted on my university's website. The university's web page needs login(the web page allows information only to university members). Currently, I have almost finished the front-end part(with dart language) for the app, and to move on, I thought I needed to enable login function first, in order to access the website information. So, I have been googling with keywords something like 'Flutter app login to web'. However, I could only find the answers for 'how to make [web app] with Flutter'. I wanted to implement login with the current front-end state because I have almost completed the front-end rather than making a 'web app' from the beginning. I don't know if searched wrong, but I could not find how to make login on the app, and how to give a push-notification whenever a new announcement is posted on the university's web page. Could anyone tell me the big picture of how I should move on to finish my app project? Would it be better if I begin my project with a 'web app' from the beginning, or is there a way to implement login to the web from my current front-end and implement a push-notification?

I am thinking to make an app that the user logs in to the app with the user's webpage account(once the user logs in after installation then the app logins automatically whenever the app is executed) and the user could register specific keyword to receive push-notification(when the new announcement posted on the website contains that keyword). With this function, the user would not need to type id, password to login to the website from a browser every time just to check if the specific notice(that the user wanted) is posted. So basically this app simply eliminates the process of logging in to the website and checking manually for specific posts.

To conclude, I want to know two things.

1. How to implement login to the website from the app (and automatic authentication)
2. How to implement push-notification for the post that contains the keyword user has registered.

Sorry for my awkward English and long question. I wrote my best to make my question understandable. I would be so much thankful if anyone could tell me how should I implement to finish my app project.

Comment: Okay so you want to login to the website from your app ? or just simply login to the app and then have notifications ?. Did you code your website as a flutter web app ?

Comment: No, my app is not a web app. I want to login to the website from my app. Actually what I want is that if the user installs the app and logins for the first time, the user does not need to login again( the app logins automatically when executed ). So, the app allows user not to type id and password everytime. Also the app saves keyword for the notifications. If a new notice on a website contains the keyword that the user has set, the app gives notification to the user. How should I implement this? :(